# Unable to obtain long value from bitwise operation

Tags: java, bitmap, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bitmask

I need to obtain the output of the following **bitwise operation** for further processing. Unfortunately anytime I attempt to convert the output to int or long types I get a Number format Exception. How do I ensure the output of a type I can process?

```
String TYPE = "type";
long TOTAL_MASK = 0xFFFFFFFF;
long BASE_INBOX_TYPE = 20;
long BASE_TYPE_MASK = 0x1F

long type = Integer.valueOf("" + TYPE + " & " + (TOTAL_MASK - BASE_TYPE_MASK) + " | " + BASE_OUTBOX_TYPE + "");
```

Comment: Two questions: 1 - Do you know what `Integer.valueOf(String)` does? 2 - Have you seen the actual value that you're calling `Integer.valueOf` with?

Comment: I understand what Integer.valueof does, in this case, the bitwise operation was generating a sort of string representation ( type & -21 ...) I was hoping to get a literal number type like long or integer from the bitwise operation so that the result would evaluate to a value that Integer.valueOf can process, for instance, Integer.valueOf(12) would work

Comment: The problem is mainly with my bitwise operation expression its not evaluating to a value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some operators apply unary numeric promotion to a single operand, which must produce a value of a numeric type and if the operand is of compile-time type byte, short, or char, it is promoted to a value of type int by a widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2).

```
String TYPE = "type";
long TOTAL_MASK = 0xFFFFFFFF;
long BASE_INBOX_TYPE = ~20; // (~)promotion to int first (not necessary)
long BASE_TYPE_MASK = 0x1F;

long type = (TOTAL_MASK - BASE_TYPE_MASK) | BASE_INBOX_TYPE;

System.out.println(type);
```

Answer (score 2):

[`Integer.valueOf(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)) is used to parse a number literal from text, not to evaluate arbitrary expression. As per method javadoc:

> The argument is interpreted as representing a signed decimal integer, exactly as if the argument were given to the `parseInt(java.lang.String)` method.

You need to write your expression as code e.g.:

```
long type = (TOTAL_MASK - BASE_TYPE_MASK) | BASE_OUTBOX_TYPE;
```

Comment: That's great, let me try it out and get back to you.

Comment: What about the bitwise operator & do we omit it in this expression. FYI am not that great at bitwise operations

Comment: This will compile, but will I get the correct value of the bitwise operation?

Comment: You can't do `"type" & int`. This expression makes no sense because `String` can't be `AND`ed with a number.

Comment: Would it make sense in this context    db.execSQL("UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME +
                " SET " + TYPE + " = (" + TYPE + " & " + (Types.TOTAL_MASK - maskOff) + " | " + maskOn + " )" +
                " WHERE " + ID + " = ?", new String[]{id + ""});

Comment: `TYPE` is a column name in the SQL query. It makes no sense to do bitwise operation here.

Comment: https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Android/blob/master/src/org/thoughtcrime/securesms/database/SmsDatabase.java Line 119